# Doxygen tool, script error "the value of property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object"

Tags: doxygen, doxywizard

Hi while opening the output of Doxygen tool. I am getting this error "The value of property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object".
I am not able to find the path of that Script in the directory.

[image]

Comment: Which version of doxygen? on what system? What do you exactly do start?

Comment: version 1.9.0
Windows 10,
Need to generate API documentation from the header files

Comment: Looks like you try to open the HTML Help file (chm file) you generated, correct? In the mean time version 1.9.1 is available (but I'm not sure this will solve your problem). Without a small example it is hard / impossible to tell what is wrong, so please add a small source code example and the settings used (that differ from the default doxygen settings, so generated with `doxygen -x Doxyfile`) that makes it possible for us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: sure, will try this